# Understanding Controlled Operation

Tags: entanglement, textbook-and-exercises

while reading an article on phase kickback, I came across this paragraph.

> When you apply a controlled operation on a target **qubit that is in an eigenstate of the unitary**, what’s essentially happening is that you’re tacking on a global phase to that target qubit.

> Normally, this wouldn’t matter but since it’s a controlled operation, **the target qubit will be in a superposition of having incurred this global phase, and not having incurred it. Thus, a relative phase is born** between the quantum states (including the control) that have the global phase and those that do not.

Please help me to understand what do following 2 lines mean

> qubit that is in an eigenstate of the unitary`

> the target qubit will be in a superposition of having incurred this global phase, and not having incurred it. Thus, a relative phase is born between the quantum states

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to see this is through an example. Consider the circuit below:

[image]

1. `qubit that is in an eigenstate of the unitary` 
   Note that $|-\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $X$. That is $X|-\rangle = -1|-\rangle$  
   Where $|-\rangle = \dfrac{|0\rangle - |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$ 
   Also note that we are apply the $CX$ gate with the bottom qubit as the target qubit, which is an eigenstate of $X$ with an eigenvalue of $-1$.

2. `the target qubit will be in a superposition of having incurred this global phase, and not having incurred it. Thus, a relative phase is born between the quantum states` 
   Note that the top qubit starts in the state $|0\rangle$ and Hadamard gate is being applied. Thus, it is now in a superposition state $\dfrac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} = |+\rangle$ 
   After the application of the Hadamard gate $H$, your two qubit state is $$|+-\rangle = \bigg(\dfrac{|0\rangle +|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \bigg) \bigg(\dfrac{|0\rangle -|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \bigg) = \dfrac{|00\rangle - |01\rangle + |10\rangle - |11\rangle}{2}$$
   Then the applying the $CX$ gate with the bottom qubit (second qubit) as the target
   $$CX \bigg(\dfrac{|00\rangle - |01\rangle + |10\rangle - |11\rangle}{2} \bigg) = \dfrac{|00\rangle - |01\rangle + |11\rangle - |10\rangle}{2}= \underbrace{\bigg(\dfrac{|0\rangle -|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \bigg)}_{\text{top qubit}}  \underbrace{\bigg(\dfrac{|0\rangle -|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \bigg)}_{\text{bottom qubit}}$$
   Note how that the top qubit start in the superposition state $|+\rangle = \dfrac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} $ before the application of the $CX$ gate. But then after the application of the $CX$ gate, it is now $\dfrac{|0\rangle - |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} $. This minus is coming from the fact that $X|-\rangle = -1 |-\rangle$. It picked up this overall phase and turned it into a relative phase.